# phantom header margin causing problems

Tags: html, css, header

So I'm having a problem where it seems the right `margin` of my header `ul` element is blocking a form from aligning correctly.

The problem:

[image]

my CSS for the `.header ul` is:

```
.header ul {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    margin:0 0 0 0;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:white;
    font-size:15px; 
    padding-left:5px;
    width:50%;
    position:relative;
}
```

what am I missing? this is driving me bananas!

Comment: You need to post the .headerContainer style as well as the html.

Comment: Is there a link to the page, or a jsfiddle?

Comment: it would be preferable to post your code so we can help you.. What you showed us tells as nothing

Comment: try this link for a jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/mk8pu41t/